# Not able to understand func<Type> code

Tags: c#

I know what a func is, but not able to understand the following piece of code:

There's a simple property :

```
    public Func<DomainFacade> BusinessFacadeFactory { get; set; }
```

And this is how the property is set:

```
    this.BusinessFacadeFactory = () => new DomainFacade();
```

Now this way of setting the property, is it a Anonymous method or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`() => new DomainFacade()` is a lambda expression

It is an **unnamed method** written in place of a `delegate`
The **compiler** converts it to a **delegate instance**

It's real format is

`(parameter)=>expression or a statement block`

Since the `func` requires a `delegate` to be assigned we can write a `lambda expression` instead of the `delegate` which would internally get **converted** to a delegate instance.

So,

`()` denotes a an empty parameter

`new DomainFacade();` is the expression

that internally gets converted to delegate by the compiler

Comment: Ok, then why do we have to declare as func<DomainFacade>. If i declare func as above, i can still say new BusinessFacade or something else

Comment: @Charu you need to declare it..cuz if u dont then how are you going to  define the `target delegate` to which you want to wire up the methods..

Comment: @Charu - As this method is stored in a variable, you can use it as a parametr to any other method. Imagine some stopwatch function. You pass this lambda/Func variable as a parametr. Stowatch will execute it (whether it is web download or 3D rendering) and return you the execution time

Answer (score 5):

That's called a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

It's a more-compact form of an anonymous method.

Answer (score 1):

`() => new DomainFacade()` is a *lambda expression*.
It is an inline method, returned as a delegate value.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lambda expression as others have said. Here is what it would break down like this in long form:

```
this.BusinessFacadeFactory = () => new DomainFacade();
```

then

```
this.BusinessFacadeFactory = new delegate(){ return new DomainFacade()};
```

then

```
...
BusinessFacadeFactory = OnBusinessFacadeFactory; 
...

private DomainFacade OnBusinessFacadeFactory()
{
  return new DomainFacade()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a lambda expression, which is shorthand for creating an anonymous method.

```
()
```

is the input parameters (i.e. none)

```
new DomainFacade();
```

is the method body.